# What are good tools for managing user acceptance testing?

Tags: manual-testing, tools, jira, user-acceptance-testing

We have `JIRA` and are using an integrated testing tool called `Kanoah` https://www.kanoah.com/. It’s OK, but basically, I feel, that there are too many `clicks`, too many `fields` and it is generally confusing.

I found a few other things that looked similar - like `TestGoat`

- similar in that there are steps and expected results.

We generally are testing how a customer goes through a lifecycle, so steps with expected results is exactly what we need - just with a cleaner, more intuitive and easier to fill out `UI`. And free would be nice too, as well as integratable with either `JIRA` or `slack`.

Sorry if my terminology is wrong - I do not know much about the world of QA.

Answer (score 4):

Jira, like Trello, VSTS, Pivotal Tracker and others are story ticket management systems.  I've used them all and prefer Jira the most due to its UI, usability and integrations with both other Atlassian tools and other vendor tools.  However I don't consider these tools at all suitable to actually details the steps to go through to execute a given test, that is the wrong use of the tool and I can imagine how painful it would be in many tools to enter all those steps as sub tasks through the UI.  Remember, spend your time building software (including automation software and tests) not artifacts and detailed supporting documentation.

Recording the steps with expected results is different, that indicates either a tool that can run tests (SeleniumIDE firefox plugin, TestNG, HPQualityCenter, etc. locally or tools such as GhostInspector that can run them in the cloud) or using a programming language, e.g. Ruby, Python, Java or C# with selenium bindings against browser instances.

Then there are tools such as Jenkins, CircleCI, VSTS, etc. that let you run suites of testing in the cloud (CI - Continuous Integration) and often have detailed setup scripts but again I don't think this is directly what you describe.

Comment: I should have made it more clear (and have updated original question) - we are not using 'normal' JIRA for the manual testing - we are using some plugin called Kanoah https://www.kanoah.com/ - it is very seemlessly integrated into JIRA. Do you know any quicker-to-fill-out tools?

Answer (score 0):

As software qa consulting organization, the best tool to manage UAT is Jira (that you are already using) integrated with Zephyr that can manage test cases as well. Jira is th best tool used as it has great UI.
Also bugzilla, HO Quality Center can also be used to manage the UAT.